# Change the value of a variable inside a function

Tags: c

I want to change a value in the stack inside another function.

```
int Function(int *var){
    int i=125;
    var = i;
}
int Function2(){
    int apple;
    Function(&apple);
    printf("%d", apple);
}
```

This shows me `error: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast` at this line `var = 125;`.

**I want to copy the value of `i` into `var` in order to get `apple = 125`. (But when I will leave the `Function`, `i` inside the stack will be freed.)**

I don't see where I made a mistake.

Comment: (a nit), but the `'*'` goes with the *variable* not the *type*, e.g. `(int *var)`. That prevents confusion in declarations as well, consider `int* a, b, c;` (`b` and `c` are *not* pointers...)

Comment: ^ the above comment is personal style, not any part of the language. Also `int *` is actually a type

Comment: `*var = i`. that's the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code `int *var = &apple` Occur.

Imagine that apple variable stored at address 0x1000000,

So var holds the address of apple. so var pointing to 0x1000000.

If you do var = i then var variable leave 0x1000000 address and hold new address as value of i which is 125, which is invalid as lower memory address can't be accessible.

So you must have to do *var = i, as this fulfill your requirement.

Answer (score 3):

You need to dereference the pointer.

```
*var = 125;
```

As written you are trying to change the address stored in the pointer (i.e., the thing the pointer is pointing to).

Comment: With your solution, `var` value = 125 and then I guess if I check the value at the `apple` memory address, I could see `125`.

Comment: @Alexis_FR_JP Yes. You're correct (I deleted my old comment as I read your comment incorrectly).

Comment: As written, the code is plainly invalid. C language does not support implicit integer-to-pointer conversion, The code has no defined behavior. So, there's no way to conclude that it is "trying to change the address stored in the pointer".

Comment: @AnT Trying and failing. The compiler error says as much.